# Get values from span elements using JS or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a few values in a few spans and I want to extract each number to a string and then perform calculations. I have the following code which will just get the value from the "example" id but how can I get the values from all the spans as well

```
$(function() {
    $a = $('#example').text();
    window.alert($a);    
});

<div id="example">
<span>1</span>
<span>,</span>
<span>9</span>
<span>9</span>
<span>3</span>
<span>,</span>
<span>1</span>
</div>
```

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: My apologies. I was rushing and didn't realise I wasn't being very clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery you can loop through them easily:

```
$('#example span').each(function(){
   console.log($(this).text());
})
```

Please, [quit using `alert()` for troubleshooting.](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/), use `console.log()` instead.

EDIT: Here is a start for getting them into a string:

```
var numbers = [];
$('#example span').each(function(){
    if(',' != $(this).text()) {
    console.log($(this).text());
    numbers.push($(this).text());
  }
})
console.log(numbers)
var numberString = numbers.toString();
console.log(numberString);
```

returns

> 1,9,9,3,1

If you don't want commas in the string then use `join()` (whatever you put in the join argument becomes the string separator):

```
var numberString = numbers.join('');
```

returns

> 19931

Comment: Thank you for this, it helps. This seems to output each number on a new line though. How would I get them all into one string?